# Rails 4 w Bootstrap 3 recieving Uncaught Error: Popover requires tooltip.js only in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Works fine on local server, when pushed to heroku I receive this error.

https://gist.github.com/tonytaudesign/94a81203c40eac992aa0

Comment: is your tooltip.js in the application.js. Are you serving your assets in production?

Comment: tooltip.js is in the vendor folder required by bootstrap file which is in the application.js.  What exactly does serving your assets in production mean?  Bootstraps layout functionality is working on production just not jquery  - thank you

Comment: Give me a link to your application.js, also print out your production enviroment.

Comment: https://github.com/tonytaudesign/tonytau/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js  - Thank you.  Just have to figure out how to print out production environment and ill send that too

Answer (score 0):

Does tooltip.js depend on jqueryui's tooltip. Are you including a jquery library with tooltip included?